# jquery datatables and mvc razorview

Tags: c#, .net, datatables

I am using the jQuery datatable plugin to make a table as a datatable. But I see on the browser that the bottom of the table also contains all the column names of the table. How do I disable this ?

Comment: From your explanation...this does not sound like a datatables issue.. but rather an HTML issue.  In your HTML you need to delete the `tfoot` element inside your table element.

Comment: How on earth can people guess at the problem without seeing any code?  Please post the HTML table and the datatables init code.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9190/is-there-a-way-to-not-repeat-column-headers-at-the-bottom-of-datatable) link on their website states to remove the TFOOT from the HTML.

Comment: I do not have a tfoot. I have only added thead and tbody.

Comment: While it may be true that you have only added those, it is possible that DataTables adds it in when initialized. I would look at that.